# Should [effects] and [special-effects] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 2 tags related to adding effects to video - [effects] and [special-effects]. The description for [effects] is:

> transformations that can be applied to an audio or video signal to achieve a desired aesthetic result.

There is no description for [special-effects] and it only has 7 questions. Perhaps they should be merged?

Answer (score 2):

There is a strong difference between these terms, but the wiki entry for them should probably be updated.  Effects are things like color adjustments, transitions, motion stabilization, etc.  Special Effects on the other hand are things like compositing things together or doing green screening or adding computer graphics, etc.  They are far more elaborate than a normal video effect or filter.

Comment: I'd definitely like an explanation of the difference. I don't understand from your description what the difference is. For example, in FCPX, if I want to do green screening, I'll apply the Keyer effect. Computer Graphics is something I would do with, say, Motion or After Effects, usually. I'd consider that Motion Graphics rather than an effect. Special Effects could be practical (make-up, miniature sets, etc.), but they're still effects. I don't think "effects" by itself implies a plug-in, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure exactly how to describe the difference, but a color correction for example is definately an effect but very much not a special effect.  I think the difference is probably in the amount of change, but I'm not sure if there is a better or more official difference.